# Mock device location from Flutter

Tags: flutter

Is there any Flutter library that can mock device location? More precisely I want to set the device location from the app.

Long story: My flutter app connects to a Bluetooth GNSS and gets the location data in NMEA format I want to route this data to another app like Qfield, and the easiest solution I see now is to force the device location with this data from the GNSS board (mock location). And the target OS is Android.